# How do I create and run NUnit/WebDriver test-suites via Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I've recently moved from a Java-JUnit4-Webdriver environment to a C#-NUnit-Webdriver one.

In Eclipse, I could create test-suites quickly by copying test classes into a test-suite class, and after minimal formatting, run them as JUnit tests. The JUnit test-suites used the pattern below:

```
       package com.example.testsuites;

            import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
            import org.junit.runners.Suite;
            import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

            import com.example.TestBase;
            import com.example.Test1;
            import com.example.Test2;
            import com.example.Test3;
            import com.example.Test12;
            import com.example.Test303;

            @RunWith(Suite.class)
            @SuiteClasses({Test1.class,
              Test2.class,
              Test3.class,
              Test12.class,
              Test303.class,
              })

            public class ExampleTestSuite extends TestBase {
         }
```

Is there an equivalent way to conveniently generate NUnit test-suite classes and then execute them in Visual Studio?

I've been reading the NUnit documentation but can find no obvious equivalent. I know that with the NUnit GUI you can select tests to run via check-boxes but this does not create a permanent test-suite. And that suites can be created by adding attributes/categories etc to individual tests but this doesn't appear as flexible as the method above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NUnit [Suite](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=suite&r=2.4.4) functionality:

```
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  private class AllTests
  {
    [Suite]
    public static IEnumerable Suite
    {
      get
      {
        ArrayList suite = new ArrayList();
        suite.Add(typeof(OneTestCase));
        suite.Add(typeof(AssemblyTests));
        suite.Add(typeof(NoNamespaceTestFixture));
        return suite;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, Suites are currently not displayed in the NUnit GUI.

- You can also consider using [`[Category]`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2) attribute instead of
  Suite functionality.
- See also related thread: [NUnit not running Suite tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919487/nunit-not-running-suite-tests).

Comment: Thanks. I found using [Category] the quickest method of grouping tests together.